# Xilinx IP for delaying data

Tags: fpga, xilinx, vivado

I am working on a block design to compute the coordinate in the complex set represented by a pixel.  Given an x and y pixel value, the step size, and starting x and starting y I need to compute a coordinate in the complex plane. For instance `x' = start_x + step * x`

Since x is an integer I first pass it though a floating point conversion module and then through a floating point fused multiply add.  This has a total latency of 24 cycles.  The problem is that I also need to provide a memory address at the beginning and get it out 24 cycles later before I pass it on the the module which gets x' y' and the address.  I am looking for an IP which can help with this.  The closest thing I have found is a shift register but I would need 24 of them.  I was thinking of maybe using a FIFO.  Is there anything that just acts as a latency delay for data while other calculations are being performed?

[image]

PS:  Not sure why I called my Fused-Mul-Add fmax

Comment: What is the throughput of the floating point conversion and fused multiply add? If it's 1 calculation per cycle, then you probably need a shift register to delay the address. If it's less (like one per 24 cycles) then you probably just need to store the address in a register, and code your floating point operations with a "done" flag to signal when the address should be retrieved (and maybe the next address shifted in?)

Comment: It is 1 per cycle.

Comment: I am doing it this way since I want to pass the data to my Mandelbrot computation module which is pipelined and I need this to feed it fast enough.

Comment: Then it sounds like you need a shift register. Maybe there is a resource-efficient way to implement it in a BRAM or something, though.

Comment: (Or look into the trick of using LUT RAM itself as shift registers. IIRC you can get a 32-bit serial shift register in a single LUT.

Comment: But the problem is I wanted something I could stick in the block diagram.

Comment: You can put the code in a module in the block designs wrapper, just make the axi ports external

Comment: If you are choosing your design components based on whether or not you can stick the component in your block diagram, I suspect you will eventually find that this design philosophy is impractical.

Answer (score 4):

Just write one. It's only a few lines of VHDL. Depth can be a generic natural, and it can take its width from the ports. Synth it independently and check that ISE/Vivado use the expected shift register mode in LUTs.

If you can't easily wrap it as a block, that calls the usefulness of the whole block diagram approach into question. Most of these things go right back to Mentor Graphics "Renoir" tool, in which wrapping VHDL as a block was easy.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need a shift register.

Luckily, shift registers can be implemented fairly efficiently in Xilinx FPGAs.

From the Kintex-7 documentation.

> A SLICEM function generator can also be configured as a 32-bit shift register without using the flip-flops available in a slice. Used in this way, each LUT can delay serial data from 1 to 32 clock cycles

So a 24-cycle delay for a 24-bit address could be implemented in just 6 CLB's (because there are 4 LUTs in each SLICEM CLB). Spartan devices should also have similar capabilities.

In older families, `SRL` was the macro used to instantiate this functionality. I'm not sure if that's still true for the current (Artix/Kintex/Virtex-7 or Spartan-6 generation) products.

Comment: The issue is that as far as I can tell the axi stream shift registers only dely 1 cycle.  I could add 24 of them but this is a pain.  Is there anyway to have a shift register with a delay of 24?

Comment: I have no idea what axi stream is or how it relates to Xilinx devices or Xilinx IP, so I can't help you with that.

Comment: It looks like I can just use the ram based shift register for my purposes so thanks.

Comment: AXI Stream is an interface from ARM. It has FIFO like control signals.

Comment: @Paebbels, in that case, I'm not clear why OP can only use Axi-Stream shift registers in his/her design.

Comment: I haven't used the schematic designer in Xilinx products since ISE 9.x, but the new IP cores are made for drag and drop design. Each core has a AXI interface for each in/output. Mostly it's AXI stream so operations can be pipelined. I asume that there is a delay core to adjust delays in the schematic design.

Comment: Yes, but in some cases you can ignore the tread signal - especially if a streaming design is followed with a fifo